# How can I make my output appear all on one line with no spaces?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a simple Javascript problem that I'm working on, where the point is to...

1. Take an input, like 123
2. Separate the input as single digits, then square those single digits, thus getting 149.
3. Display that "149" (in this case) as an output.

I don't know how to display it as 149. I can only show it as

1

4

9

Sure, I might try adding it to an array then for looping the results... something tells me that this is the slow solution, and that there is a faster one. Here's my code.

```
function squareDigits(num) {
    //Convert input to string
    num = num + "";
    var newnum;
    var len = num.length;

    //Split into digits, and square that result baby
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var digit = num.substr(i, 1);
        newnum = Math.pow(digit, 2);
        console.log(newnum);
    }

}

squareDigits(123);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create empty array outside of the loop
2. Add squares of the each digit in the array
3. Join the array after loop finishes

```js
function squareDigits(num) {
  num = '' + num;
  var len = num.length;

  var squares = []; // Define empty array
  //Split into digits, and square that result baby
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var digit = num.substr(i, 1);
    squares.push(Math.pow(digit, 2)); // Push the square of the digit at the end of array
  }

  return squares.join(''); // Join the array elements with empty string as glue
}

var squares = squareDigits(123);
console.log(squares);
document.write(squares);
```

---

By string concatenation

1. Declare a empty string before the for loop
2. Concatenate the square of the digit to the string by first casting the number to string

```js
function squareDigits(num) {
  //Convert input to string
  num = num + "";
  var newnum = ''; // Decalare variable with Empty string
  var len = num.length;

  //Split into digits, and square that result baby
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var digit = num.substr(i, 1);
    newnum += '' + Math.pow(digit, 2); // Cast the square to string and then concatenate to the string
  }

  return newnum; // Return the string
}

var squares = squareDigits(123);
document.write(squares);
```

Comment: Thanks. The only thing I added was multiplying the result by 1, since I forgot to mention that the result needs to have type conversion to an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Try utilizing `String.prototype.split()` , `Array.prototype.map()` , `Array.prototype.join()`

```js
function squareDigits(num) {
  return String(num).split("")
    .map(function(n) {
      return Math.pow(n, 2);
    }).join("");
}
console.log(squareDigits(123));
```

Comment: Good thinking about using `split` and `map` +1

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
function squareDigits(num) {
    //Convert input to string
    num = num + "";
    var newnum;
    var len = num.length;
    var digits = '';

    //Split into digits, and square that result baby
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var digit = num.substr(i, 1);
        newnum = Math.pow(digit, 2);
        digits += '' + newnum

    }
    console.log(digits);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try `process.stdout.write`, as in

```
process.stdout.write(newnum);
```